# QML-like approaches or programming languages?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, programming-languages, qml

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), QML is a declarative, reactive, scripting programming language. It also seems to be a unique language. Nothing similar to it apparently exists, while many other programming languages in wide use today shamelessly copy ideas from one another.

**Do there exist programming languages or approaches within a language (such as within C++), that mimick QML?**

The reason that I'm asking is because that I'm trying to implement my own QML-like language and compiling it into Lua, but it is hard work. Something even remotely similar to QML might do the job instead.

Comment: There are many questions about a programming language, that were not closed, here's one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679792/which-programming-language-for-a-calendar-software . I'll remove the reference to "implementation".

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254944/456814) in order to determine if it's on-topic for Stack Overflow. See also [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

In the same year QML was released (2009), Microsoft released [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language).

XAML works together with C#, like QML and C++ do. JavaScript is also integrated.

```
<canvas debug="true">
  <button name="button1" text="Click me !">
    <handler name="onclick">
      parent.button1.setAttribute("text","Hello, World !"); // JavaScript-Code
    </handler>
  </button>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Inside XAML you can integrate your JavaScript Code. Maybe it’s not comfortable as it is in QML. Look at the code I added.

Comment: The example is nice, though `XAML` is not a programming language. You embed a script into it, just like any other string.